# Is there an event listener which allows to handle the cases when object keys are deleted with the delete operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser

There is a MutationObserver for DOM nodes, but it doesn't help with regular JavaScript Objects.
It is possible to track when properties are accessed or modified by defining using Object.defineProperty() or through getters/setters, but when properties are deleted using the `delete` operator, the getters/setters can't track it.

So, this question is about detecting the event when a key or property is being deleted from an object with the `delete`. Here is a short code snippet to elaborate the requirement:

```
var x = 100;
// some other stuffs..
// and somewhere else
delete window.x; // <------ how to detect this event?
```

In short, how to listen to the delete operator calls.

Comment: Can you specify your use case more specifically?

Comment: You're probably looking for [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/deleteProperty) but I'm not really sure you can do it with `window`

Comment: We needed to solve this problem to maintain some old pieces of code that when object keys or properties are deleted anywhere we needed a way to handle them properly and restore proper state so as to match new requirements without modifying the old source code. Unfortunately, Proxy objects won't work with Window.

Comment: @user3330840 "*maintain some old pieces of code*" and "*without modifying the old source code*" seem incompatible to me. Really, you should throw out and fix old, bad code.

Comment: Yeah, but regardless, it would be good to know the possible solutions or possible tips and tricks to tackle the main problem here: how to detect delete operator calls. Alternatively, just for some particular use cases, it might be fine to simply track when variables are in and out of scope, but still that might not be possible either for window or is it?